TypeError: can't access property "password.request", this.t.routes is undefined in production
I am using Laravel 11.0 with Inertia and Vue. My application in working properly in development environment but i have error in production.
I Deployed my app to Shared hosting using Cpanel and when i try to to access some views where i use  route('route_name'), i have a blank page with this error in my browser console
TypeError: can't access property "password.request", this.t.routes is undefined
Here is my login page page section from where the error is thrown
 <Link v-if="canResetPassword"
       :href="route('password.request') "
       class="link text-sm">
        {{__('Forgot your password?')}}
 </Link>

I have try to Clean my browser cache and application cache using php artisan optimize:clear, but nothing changed.
